# postgresql check if exists while executing prepared statement

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm preparing some statements and want to check if the row exists before I update. If it exists then update it, if it doesn't then output a message "No such animal". I have the update bit working, but unsure how to check if the row exists. Please assist.

```
$v = array();
$v[] = $_POST['status'];
$v[] = $_POST['id'];

$dbh = dbh_get();

$sql = 'UPDATE tap SET status=?
    WHERE id =?';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($v);

\\ if row isn't there display message "No such animal"

\\ otherwise print the below

printf("Status was changed to - %s", $v[0]);

\\then either way have my continue button for me to click on

print '<div class="button" style="float:left;" onclick="window.location.href=\'admin.php\';">Admin</div>' . "\n";

dbh_free($dbh)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you want to check if the row exists before performing update. you can try this -

```
 $id_exist = 0;
 $sql = "SELECT id
         FROM tap" ;

$sql_prepare = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sql_prepare->execute();
while($row = $sql_prepare->fetchObject()) {
   if($_POST['id'] == $row->id) {
      $id_exist = 1;
    } 

}
if($id_exist == 1) {
// perform update here
} else {
  echo 'No such animal';
 }
```

Comment: nope, now the statement doesn't work whats the 'try' for?

Comment: I need to do something with the PDO at the top of the statement as well I think?

Comment: try is used to inspect a piece of code whether it has any exception or not. If the statement throw any exception then catch block can catch it. In your case if the update statement fails to update then it should enter the catch block and print "update failed " as well as the exception.

Comment: ok, I looked it up and it makes sense, really I want it to give me an error if the id doesn't exist. Something simple like "No such Customer registered." I might reword the question. Because perhaps it's my statement at fault for not checking if it exists somehow.

Comment: Solved my problem, appreciate the assist